# How to properly structure a multi-module maven project when a module is required by many projects?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, multi-module

So i have been working to figure out how to make a multi-module maven project that allows multiple projects to depend on one core module that also will package to a JAR. What is the proper structure for this?

For the record, I originally had no aggregator pom and it builds/debugs fine but I can not build a jar. And after playing with this now I can not even import the same module in to 2 separate projects and can no longer even debug/run.

I think my problem stems from the fact I am creating dependencies wrong in intellij, but this is just a guess. I have historically been going to module settings -> dependencies and importing a maven project so that my poms recognize the other modules. Intellij does not seem to like this as it constantly deletes my modules from other projects.

So the following criteria should be met:

- one central core module
- One project specific module per parent
- multiple projects depending on the core module
- All maven projects
- Must be packaged as a jar
- core + secondary module should be editable in each intellij instance

So I've tried a ton of structures, but my final attempt here is the following:

Parent POM/project that points to 2 existing modules. One of these modules will be used in another project of similar structure.

I have tried setting maven dependencies across all these poms in different configurations but I still get no manifest or noclassdeffound when building and/or can not build at all or get cyclical dependencies.

here is the parent pom:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>TEST</groupId>
    <artifactId>CLIENT-PARENT</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <modules>
        <module>../TEST-SHARED-CORE</module>
        <module>../TEST-CLIENT-CLI</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

This is child A (core) pom:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>TEST</groupId>
    <artifactId>TEST-SHARED-CORE</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
      ...
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

and the second child module pom:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-  4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0

</modelVersion>

    <groupId>TEST</groupId>
    <artifactId>TEST-CLIENT-CLI</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>TEST</groupId>
        <artifactId>CLIENT-PARENT</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../TEST-CLIENT-PARENT</relativePath>
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>TEST</groupId>
            <artifactId>TEST-SHARED-CORE</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



</project>
```

I get the impression my structure is terribly incorrect, So what is the proper structure?

EDIT:

When this does package/build this is what happens when the JAR is run, it does not find the classes in shared-core.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/shared/networking/contexts/NetworkContext
        at com.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Comment: Did you put the parent and the modules into _the same_ git/svn repository?

Comment: No i have not, I am not currently using git or svn. Do i have to create a repo for this? I did plan to integrate with git soon but I want to get this building first.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you first learn a version control system before continue to work on Software or on using build system etc...

Comment: I am familiar with git, however i do not believe any version control would be needed to build a maven project. Is this an incorrect assumption? Maven however, I am not very familiar with, so if git integration is required to build a project that would be good to know.

Comment: Git is not needed for Maven, but you will not get around it when you try to do something serious. Anyway, make sure that you have a sensible directory structure for your multi-module project. I recommend to put the modules into subdirectories of the parent and reference them without using `.../`

Comment: About the edit: Running a single jar on the command line does not work unless you explicitly specify the dependencies on the command line or build a fat jar in Maven.

Comment: Yea I tried shading it and it worked, I was under the assumption it compiled dependent IntelliJ modules automatically which was not the case. Once i packaged with shade it ran beautifully. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're basic structure looks ok. I'd add the packaging element to the CORE and CLI modules

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

so maven knows to build a jar file.

EDIT 2

I believe your current structure is

```
parent ( a pom with modules )
- core ( a jar )
- cli  ( a jar )
```

i think this relativePath is incorrect

```
<relativePath>../TEST-CLIENT-PARENT</relativePath>
```

since this indicates that

```
root ( a pom with only modules )
- parent ( a pom with common jar dependencies)
- core ( a jar )
- cli  ( a jar )
```

While you are hoping to build everything as a multi-module project, i will be the case that for the first build you will build the parent/root submodule individually.

The root pom which

Comment: I tried this and there is no change. I was under the impression they were defaulting to JAR already as I have the maven compiler plugin enabled. But the bigger problem is I cant figure out how to link this all in with intellij. The guides online are for new projects but I am importing existing modules. I think my intellij dependency config is conflicting with maven.

I think my problem is more in how I am linking it to intellij and trying to import maven modules in the module settings page, is that something I should be doing? or should it all be through maven via relative paths?

Comment: Can you post the full build log message you currently get?

Comment: As of the last 5 minutes it is currently building, I added a partial stack trace of what happens when the compiled jar is run. Essentially, there are no shared-core classes in the final jar. I have tried adding shared-core as both a maven and intellij dependency

Comment: Never try to add dependencies outside Maven.

Comment: This seems to be the problem here... I just was unsure how to get the module to show up in intellijs project window without adding it as a dependency. I will look in to that.

Comment: Ok so essentially structure is: All folders parallel to each-other in one directory. Again the core module will have multiple parents so i cant create a root/parent then nest the modules inside, right? So the path is correct, the parent is parallel to the child (pom is ../TEST-CLIENT-PARENT/pom.xml from TEST-CLIENT-CLI/pom.xml).  Is this directory structure flawed?

Comment: A module cannot have more than one parent.